# Crystal Report Java Varchar/String Formula

Tags: java, sql, crystal-reports

Fields saved with Java &'s in them.

This is my current formula:

```
Local StringVar leftcut;
Local StringVar rightcut;
leftcut := Left({table.field},len({table.field})-1); 
rightcut := Right(leftcut,len(leftcut)-1);
Replace (rightcut,"&" , ", ");
```

However, it is cutting off the first character of the string now. Anything? I would rather stick with this formula but any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected output